# Mysql won't restart on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

Mysql won't restart again, I get this error :

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and here tail error log :

```
sudo tail -30 /var/log/mysql/error.log
2018-07-09T18:22:31.107868Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-07-09T18:22:31.204826Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-07-09T18:22:31.707270Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-07-09T18:22:31.707323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709057Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written. Only 376832 bytes written. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709080Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709092Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 2097152, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 376832 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709103Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709110Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709119Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709126Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2018-07-09T18:22:31.709133Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-07-09T18:22:32.210454Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-07-09T18:22:32.210480Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-07-09T18:22:32.210490Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-07-09T18:22:32.210500Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-07-09T18:22:32.210508Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-07-09T18:22:32.210527Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-07-09T18:22:32.219434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2018-07-09T18:22:32.219459Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
```

Please any one had this error ?

Comment: Probably want to solve the disk write failure regarding file size or disk space? You can check free space with `df -h`. I doubt it's file size, as that's pretty small. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/mysql-error-28-no-space-left-on-the-device

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a case where reading messages carefully can help you a great deal. Your messages say...

> 2018-07-09T18:22:31.709092Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 2097152, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 376832 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
>
> 2018-07-09T18:22:31.709103Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'

It looks like the disk holding your MySQL data is full.  Do `df -h`.

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/root  20G   19G    0  100%  / 
devtmpfs  7.9G     0 7.9G    0%  /dev 
tmpfs     7.9G     0 7.9G    0%  /dev/shm 
tmpfs     7.9G   14M 7.9G    1%  /run 
tmpfs     5.0M     0 5.0M    0%  /run/lock 
tmpfs     7.9G     0 7.9G    0%  /sys/fs/cgroup 
tmpfs     7.9G     0 7.9G    0%  /run/shm 
/dev/sda2 487M   22M 437M    5%  /boot 
/dev/sda4 1.8T  376M 1.7T    1%  /home
```

Ubuntu/Debian puts MySQL at /var/lib/mysql. On your machine `/var` is on the root file system, shown first in your `df` output. **That file system is full.**

Without knowing what else is on your system it's hard to tell you exactly what to do. But, your /var directory tree needs to be on a bigger file system, or you need to figure out how to put your MySQL data under /home.

Comment: Thanks for reply and sorry for delay,
Please how can I increase dev/root space ?

Comment: You can't easily increase the size of `/`. You can move your MySQL data directory to someplace on `/home`, though. Plenty of instructions for this are online.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Disk volume

```
df -h
```

It is possible that the server is full.

Delete extra files or increase the volume

Answer (score 1):

MYQL is failing to start because as the Journalctl output indicates, but you haven't provided the mandatory server-id. Add the mandatory id as indicated in the code below.

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Change from:

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog-format = 'ROW'
```

Change to:

```
server-id=master-01
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog-format = 'ROW'
```

This will get your server running while you address the proper formatting of your desired logging.

non-fatal warnings:

For the open files limit of your error you will have to either decrease the demand in the configuration you edited or increase the system's limits with:

```
/etc/security/limits.conf

* soft nofile [new number]
* hard nofile [new number]
```

The first column describes WHO the limit is to apply for. '' is a wildcard, meaning all users. To raise the limits for root, you have to explicitly enter 'root' instead of ''.